# How to link MaxCDN to BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, cdn

I have a bitbucket account and I want to use MaxCDN PULL ZONE to point to.

Answer (score 2):

This is my first Question on Stack.. Thought I would answer as well.

you point the MaxCDN PULL ZONE to: 
http://<-team->.bitbucket.org/<-project->/
- then images/ or css/ or js/

Then you setup a CNAME for the MaxCDN PULL Zone url.

Example:
cdn.domain.com > mycdn.maxcdn-domain.com > http://<-team->.bitbucket.org/<-project->/

I setup the bitbucket account like this example 
http://mg.bitbucket.org/

so like this https://bitbucket.org/<-team->/<-team->.bitbucket.org